# Tetris [PyGame] - Let the shapes fall

Tags: python, pygame, 2d-games, tetris

I'm trying to clone the Tetris game and already have PyGame pick a random shape and display it. I drew an array-backed grid and 'told' PyGame to draw colored squares in certain cells in order to get the cells.

```
def iShape(): 
    grid [0][5] = 3 
    grid [0][6] = 3
    grid [0][7] = 3
    grid [0][8] = 3
    pygame.init()
```

this tells the system on which cell of the grid it will draw the square in order to get the shape.

```
def draw():
    allShapes = ['''all Shapes that I defined''']
    pick = random.choice (allShapes)
    ... #otherstuff
    if pick == iShape: 
        if grid[row][column] == 3:
                    color = orange
                    #draw the squares
```

I have been trying to think of how I could let the shapes fall slowly so the player can move/rotate them before they hit the ground but none of my ideas work out. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Where is your games mainloop? Show that code.

Comment: @RobertB That is pretty much all I have. The rest of the code is just setting the display, drawing the grid and drawing the other shapes.

Answer (score 0):

try to create a def called clock or tick(anything) and have that control the drop speed. or you could youse the in built python timer by doin inport mathand there is a command to have times so you could have then drop a pice of the grid every second or something like that sry about the brightness

Answer (score 0):

I've found a Tetris clone called Tetromino online. I can't quite say it will work as it probably uses a different code style, but you could get an idea from it. Its at the link https://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapter7.html